# Create a Youtube Player in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I want to create a Youtube video player with an iframe. This is my script:

```
function play(id){
   var str = window.location.href;
   var lastSlash = str.lastIndexOf("=");
   var id = str.substring(lastSlash+1);
   document.getElementById('idder').value = id;
   var i = document.getElementById('idder').value;

   document.getElementById('player').src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + i + "?autoplay=1";
   //document.querySelector(".menuwrap").innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="32" id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" autoplay></iframe>';
}
```

But for change the video I must click two times and I don't know why. I hope that you help me :)

Comment: You might want to look into using the player API for youtube. This will make things much easier and give you more control over the player events. https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: Can you give me an example for realize my script? Thanks.

Comment: And can I create the same thing with my initial script?

Comment: The reference link has sample source code and explains everything you need to know. Spend a little time reading through it and run a few test. It will be well worth the time and as I pointed out before, you will have more control over the player events. If you still have problems getting it to work, edit your question with the new source code you're trying to use and leave another message, I will be more than happy to help once you take the time to read the reference and make an attempt.

Comment: I tried but I have the same result.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the new source code you're trying. If you add the new source code in your question I can look at why the player API isn't working for you and answer the question without it being downvoted due to making a large change to your original source code.